# Efficient string suffix search in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-indexes

I would like to find all rows that would match the predicate `MyColumn LIKE '%FooBar'` but by by using an index seek rather than a scan.

One approach is essentially to create a reversed version of MyColumn and search for the reversed pattern (`ooF%`) on that column with a conventional index on the reversed column.

I do not like manually creating this reversed column, however. Oracle has the concept of reversed key indexes that can automatically index on `REVERSE(MyColumn)` without the need for manually materializing reversed versions of the column (either in form of a physical column on the table or by creating an indexed view).

Are there any other ways to perform suffix substring searches in SQL Server efficiently?

Comment: Is [Full text search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) an option?

Comment: @Bridge: Full text search will not help you with this problem. From your own link: "Full-text queries perform linguistic searches against text data in full-text indexes by operating on words and phrases based on rules of a particular language such as English or Japanese". You can't search part of words with that.

Comment: @TToni You can search for words and phrases (`One or more specific words or phrases (simple term)` and `A word or a phrase where the words begin with specified text (prefix term)`) but it seems you're right - not suffixes - see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392348/whats-wrong-with-my-fulltext-search-query).

Comment: Reverse key index is really intended as a performance enhancement.  It prevents overactive page splitting/lopsided B-trees in the index files when indexing a sequential key.  Not really meant for optimizing a suffix search.

Comment: @John Wu: You are right. The hack will only work on single-byte character strings, and not e.g. UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a calculated field with an index, or an indexed view with the reversed field.

Yes, this will materialise the reversed field. But how do you think Oracle's reversed indexes work?

For the search to be efficient, there must be a materialised data structure to search.

Comment: There is a clear difference between exposing the reversed string as an actual table column, and hiding this search technicality inside an index as this string-reversing is somewhat irrelevant with respect to the business model.
But it seems there is no way to do efficient suffix search without exposing the reversed string data explicitly, so I guess you answered my question. :-)