# How to query SQL Server database of Active Directory objects by their distinguishedName?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have *two* database tables, each with a list of Active Directory hosts in column A and the `distinguishedName` of their Organizational Unit (i.e. their location in Active Directory) in Column B. The OU levels can go from 3 to 11 levels.

- `Table1` is a distinct list of hosts and their OU locations aligned to a specific application configuration.

  | `Host` | `Location` |
  | --- | --- |
  | 'HostA' | `OU=Production,OU=SubApp,OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com` |
  | 'HostB' | `OU=Development,OU=SubApp2,OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com` |
- `Table2` contains a list of all hosts in all Active Directory OUs for the entire company.

  | `Host` | `Location` |
  | --- | --- |
  | 'HostC' | `OU=Pre-Prod,OU=SubApp3,OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com` |

---

If I wanted to `JOIN` the two database tables and run a query for a distinct `Table1` Active Directory level 3 OU to obtain a return of all `Table2` hosts in that matching `Table1` Level 3 OU as well as any `Table2` hosts in any child Active Directory OUs on the domain. Would that be possible?

Example:

- Table1/HostA resides in `OU=Production,OU=SubApp,OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com`
- Table1/HostB resides in `OU=Development,OU=SubApp2,OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com`
- **Table2**/HostC resides in `OU=Pre-Prod,OU=SubApp3,OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com`

How would I write a query to return all hosts if the input Active Directory OU was (as an example) `OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com`? That way I would see HostA, HostB and HostC (despite the fact that HostC is not found in Table1).

Comment: In `Table1`, does every row (i.e. every `( Host, Location )`  pair) in `Table1` have a corresponding row in `Table2`?

Comment: Yes every host/location in Table 1 would exist in Table 2.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your search predicate(s) can reduce down to trivial string prefix or suffix matches on those `distinguishedName` paths then those queries are straightforward as you *won't* need to parse or split-up those `distinguishedName` paths.

For example, (looking at *only* your `Table2` table):

| Example | Query |
| --- | --- |
| Find objects in `OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com` | `WHERE Location = 'OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com'` |
| Find objects in `OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com` *and/or any descendant OU* | `WHERE Location LIKE '%OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com'` |
| Find objects in descendant OUs of `OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com`, but not the `App` OU itself | `WHERE Location LIKE '%,OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com'` |

<sub>(This *does* feel like a hack, but the query is sound: a query using `LIKE '%OU=...` will not match any unintended `distinguishedName` values, as [according to Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ldap/distinguished-names) there are no other RDN attribute names that end-with `OU`, but be careful if you do `LIKE '%C=...` because `DC=` also matches).</sub>

**A word on performance:** Queries using `LIKE '%...'` for suffix matches are going to be slooooow unless you make a reversed-string index, see below.

---

> a query for a distinct `Table1` Active Directory level 3 OU to obtain a return of all `Table2` hosts in that matching `Table1` Level 3 OU....

<sub>(I'm unsure exactly what you mean by *"a query for a distinct `Table1` Active Directory level 3 OU"*, but anyway...)</sub>

**Assuming** that `Table2` is a superset of `Table1` (i.e. that every `( Host, Location )` pair in `Table1` exists in `Table2`) then you just want this:

```
DECLARE @threeLevelsDeepOU varchar(100) = '%OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com';

SELECT
    t2.Host,
    t2.Location,
    CASE WHEN t1.Host IS NULL THEN 1 END AS IsInTable1
FROM
    Table2 AS t2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON
        t1.Host = t1.Host
        AND
        t2.Location = t2.Location
WHERE
    t2.Location LIKE @threeLevelsDeepOU
```

> ... as well as any `Table2` hosts in any child Active Directory OUs on the domain. Would that be possible?

This is ultimately the same query criteria as above, so just use the above query.

---

**Re: Perofmrnace and indexing:**

Note that string-suffix matches are tricky in SQL because an ordinary `INDEX` over `Location` will only help matching prefixes: an `INDEX` is no-help for "ends-with" predicates: [the trick is to *reverse* the string (in a computed-column)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19134940/159145) and then create an `INDEX` over that, so you'll want to do this:

```
ALTER TABLE [Table1 and Table2]
    ADD LocationRev AS ( REVERSE( Location ) ) PERSISTED NOT NULL;

CREATE INDEX IX_LocationRev ON [Table1 and Table2] ( LocationRev ) INCLUDE ( Host, Location );
```

Then you can query *super fast* like this:

| Example | Query | Effective Prefix Match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Find objects in `OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com` | `WHERE Location = 'OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com'` |  |
| Find objects in `OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com` *or any descendant OU* | `WHERE LocationRev LIKE REVERSE( '%OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com'` ) | `'moc=CD,1niamoD=CD,ppA=UO%'` |
| Find objects in descendant OUs of `OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com`, but not the `App` OU itself | `WHERE Location LIKE '%,OU=App,DC=Domain1,DC=com'` | `'moc=CD,1niamoD=CD,ppA=UO,%'` |

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. 

I've realized something in my previous assessment of the data that I was incorrect about. 

Table 2 contains both the host and location data, but table 1 only contains the location data. So I'd need to extract all hosts from table 2 that equal the location in table1 or is like the location in table 1.

Comment: Just to clarify:

Table 1 has a subset list of AD OUs

Table 2 has a list of all AD OUs and the Hosts configured within those OUs

I'm attempting to do an extract that returns the Table 1 OU and lists the hosts within it, and also return any child AD OUs identified in table 2 below that Table 1 OU as well as the hosts configured in them.

As you've suggested, I'd need to search it based on the distinguished name. Unfortunately  I'm not able to create an index or alter a table.